# arrow in a diagram

Tags: math-mode, diagrams, arrows, xy-pic

in the following code that encodes a diagram:

```
\xymatrix{a\ar[rr]^{\varphi\qquad}&\ar@{^{(}->}[d]&b\ar@{=}[r]&a\ar[rr]^\varphi&\ar[dd]&b \\ a\ar[rd]^{\quad\circlearrowright}\ar[rr]^{\varphi\qquad}&&b\ar[ld]^\psi&
\circlearrowright&&\\&c~\ar[rrr]&&&\mathbf{1}&~.}
```

I would like that the bottow arrow goes from the whole diagram with the triangular shape to `\mathbf{1}`. Instead it seems with this code that the bottom arrow goes from `c` to `\mathbf{1}`.

Do you have an idea how to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is easier to help you if you add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) that takes the form `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{....}\begin{document}...\end{document}`. If possible, it should compile and have the minimum amount of code needed to illustrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to troubleshoot your problem - and much more likely that they will! Certainly here it would be nice to know what packages you need:)

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot of your current output and a little drawing of what you want to have? This would be much easier. Nesting diagrams as you'd like to do is not possible in `xy` or `tikz-cd`. Please also complete your code to make it compilable (at least `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{mathabx}`

Comment: What do you mean by *the whole diagram*? Where should be the initial point of the arrow? In the center of the triangle? In some edge?